# InfluxDB syntactic difference

Tags: influxdb

Is there any difference between this two forms?

```
myMetric value1=1,value2=2
```

and this

```
myMetric.value1 v=1
myMetric.value2 v=2
```

Both store the same data (two points). Obviously, they are accessible in different way, but I mean is there any difference in storage, performance etc? As per [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtEalnKT25I&t=218), the first one gets converted to the second one, at least semantically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Influx docs for influx line protocol:

`<measurement>[,<tag_key>=<tag_value>[,<tag_key>=<tag_value>]] <field_key>=<field_value>[,<field_key>=<field_value>] [<timestamp>]`

You first form inserts one record into measurement `myMetric` without tags, two fields (`value1`,`value2`) having values `1` and `2` respectively. Since there is not timestamp supplied in data server timestamp will be used for data point.

In second case you are creating two separate measurements: `myMetric.value1` and `myMetric.value2` each having one field named `v` with values `1` and `2` respectively. Timestamps for them are likely to be different too, taking into account default nanosecond precision.

So, these two cases are not equivalent.

Using `influx` cli tool these cases look like:

```
> INSERT myMetric value1=1,value2=2
> show measurements
name: measurements
name
----
myMetric
> show field keys from myMetric
name: myMetric
fieldKey fieldType
-------- ---------
value1   float
value2   float
> select * from myMetric
name: myMetric
time                value1 value2
----                ------ ------
1526032578114702408 1      2
```

For the second case:

```
> INSERT myMetric.value1 v=1
> INSERT myMetric.value2 v=2
> show measurements
name: measurements
name
----
myMetric.value1
myMetric.value2
> select * from "myMetric.value1"
name: myMetric.value1
time                v
----                -
1526032859752277164 1
> select * from "myMetric.value2"
name: myMetric.value2
time                v
----                -
1526032864711858673 2
```

As you see in case 1 you have 1 insert operation into one measurement for one datapoint with two fields in it. In case 2 there are two insert operations into two distinct measurements having one field each.

Thus if in your use case value1 and value2 are usually inserted together I would expect first variant to be more performant. Case 2 will require 2 inserts for same data. Storage usage is likely to be approximately the same.

If value1 and value2 are inserted independently and at different times case 2 can be a bit more efficient in terms of storage as it will not have to store nulls for datapoints like `(null,2)` or `(1,null)`.

Also having data fields in separate measurements has another drawback:
queries like:

```
> select value1, value2,value2-value1 from myMetric
name: myMetric
time                value1 value2 value2_value1
----                ------ ------ -------------
1526032578114702408 1      2      1
```

won't be possible in second case.

Comment: Let's say I don't care about the timestamps being slightly different. I asked mostly about the performance and storage requirements.

Comment: 1 insert against 2 is a performance diff. Extra nulls stored for missing  field values in first case is a minor storage penalty versus 2 measurementsand hence 2 64bit timestamps to store instead of 1. You can also consider using measurement schema with one field `v` and tag `name` for value names.